# Angular ngClass set dynamically

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 9.

**Question**

How do I populate the following:

```
[ngClass]="{'is-invalid': approvalEditFormGroup.get('userName[0][0]').touched && approvalEditFormGroup.get('userName[0][0]').invalid}"
```

As you can see, I have hard-coded `'userName[0][0]'`. Is it possible to replace the `0` values with the `i` and `j` variables?

I have the following:

**html**

```
<input formControlName="{{getFieldName(i,j)}}" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': approvalEditFormGroup.get('userName[0][0]').touched && approvalEditFormGroup.get('userName[0][0]').invalid}">
```

**ts**

```
  public getFieldName(i: number, j: number): string {
    return 'userName['+i+']['+j+']';
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Now the `i` and `j` are just part of the string, so you need to use the actual `i` and `j` values

```html
<input formControlName="{{getFieldName(i,j)}}" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': approvalEditFormGroup.get('userName['+i+']['+j+']').touched && approvalEditFormGroup.get('userName['+i+']['+j+']').invalid}">
```